# Cypress is not closing menu when I click on a button from menu

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vuetify.js, cypress

Here I am testing a Vue application using cypress. I have a menu on my app screen. Normally when I click a button on the menu it closes the menu and performs the functionality. But when I do it using cypress, it performs the functionality but it can't close the menu.
Here is my sample code.

```
it('Open menu, Click on sort button(A -> Z): Check ascending order of data', function () {
    cy.server();
    cy.route("GET", getTableListAPI).as('getTableList');
    cy.route("GET", getFirstPageTableData).as("getTableDetails");
    //Asc sort Api
    cy.route("GET", ascendingSortApi).as("getAscData");
    cy.visit(testTargetURL);
    //Wait to load data
    cy.wait('@getTableList');
    //Select the target tablefrom the left pane
    cy.get(selectors.navigationDrawer).find('a').contains(testTableWithData).click();
    //Wait to load data
    cy.wait('@getTableDetails');

    //Open menu
    cy.get('th').eq(1).find('button').click();
    //Click on first button.
    cy.get(selectors.filterMenu).within(($menu) => {
        cy.get('.v-item-group').find('button').eq(0).click();
    })
    //Wait to load data
    cy.wait('@getAscData');

    //Check visibility
    cy.get(selectors.filterMenu).should('not.be.visible');
    //Check ascending order data
    cy.get('table').within(($table) => {
        cy.get('tr').find('td').should('contain','');
        cy.get('tr').find('td').should('contain','-9223372036854776000');
    })
 })
```

**Note:** I have also tried

1. click({ force: true });
2. cy.wait(500) // Following (https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/3135#issuecomment-454420548) this issue.

But still, it is not working for me. Please suggest something else for me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me the problem is that you are using {force:true} and that doesn`t trigger the function to close the menu. Try selecting some parent element of the button that is native to the menu and click it.

Comment: Is your point about cy.get() function?
Additionally I want to inform you that I have tried
`cy.get(selectors.filterMenu).within(($menu) => {
            cy.get('.col').contains('A').click();  //Also with { force: true }
  })`


And also..
`cy.get('.v-list').find('.col').find('button').eq(0).click(); 

cy.get('.v-list').find('.col').contains('A').click();`

Comment: Hi sorry for being unclear. That was one of my first tries to give an answer here in StackOverflow, I`m used to answering in facebook groups. 

I meant that you should check which component has the on click event and - the code of that event - when and how it is applied. 

If you think my anwser was inappropriate I`ll delete it.